# Collaborative Online Markdown Editor, any suggestion?

Tags: tools

I am searching for a Markdown Editor that has these features:

- Works online & offline
- Real-time collaboratiion (just like Google Docs)
- Live preview
- Commenting feature
- WYSIWYG controls

Thanks in advance

Comment: Google Drive is one but I think you probably already know it, but why would you like another one?

Comment: Can you have real-time collaboration that is offline?

Comment: @S.Mitchell that's a good question. I guess you can, but then you need a very good merging tool

Comment: @CherryPlaysRoblox Google Drive is the road I took in the end, with the integration of **StackEdit** (see my answer below)

Answer (score 5):

## In a nutshell

I decided to use **StackEdit** within **Google Drive**.

So far **StackEdit** has been great. It takes a little while to load up (5-10 sec) a given doc, but once it's loaded the experience is extremely enjoyable.

---

## How to connect StackEdit with Google Drive

You can watch [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAx_Xf0KNfg), or follow the steps below.

#### 1st step: click on “connect more apps”

[image: 1st step: click on “connect more apps”]

#### 2nd step: search for “StackEdit” & click on “+connect”

[image: 2nd step: search for “StackEdit” & click on “+connect”]

#### 3rd step: use it by: “create a new doc” and choose the "StackEdit" option

[image: 3rd step: use it by: “create a new doc” and choose the "StackEdit" option]

---

## Various Collaborative Online Markdown Editors

These are the interesting solutions I came across.

#### StackEdit

- http://stackedit.io
- Platforms MacOS, Linux, Windows
- has both Markdown syntax highlighting and near-realtime preview, as well as integrating with Google Drive and Dropbox for file synchronisation
- works online & offline + real-time collaboration + commenting + WYSIWYG controls + Live preview + spell checking + customizable UI + more
- synchronize your documents on Google Drive, Dropbox or to publish them on GitHub, Blogger…
- people say it’s not being developed anymore https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/issues/1071 but then StackEdit just launched a beta version of the 5th version

#### Classeur

- http://classeur.io
- developed by the same team as StackEdit
- in beta?
- real-time collaboration + commenting + pandoc-powered export to loads of different formats
- "Classeur was designed to be a holistic writing and collaboration environment. Its focus lies on simplifying the creative process of writing and providing the user with functions for sharing his writing with others to receive constructive feedback. Similar to StackEdit, Classeur uses Markdown as its native language of composition.” https://classeur.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/208540035-What-is-the-difference-between-StackEdit-and-Classeur-

#### HackMD

- https://hackmd.io
- simple markdown-aware editor + live preview + simultaneous editing
- maybe issues with simultaneous editing

---

## Sources

- https://beegit.com/collaborative-markdown
- https://erambler.co.uk/blog/collaborative-markdown-editing
- https://www.slant.co/topics/2196/~online-markdown-editor
- https://alternativeto.net/software/stackedit/

Comment: Can you share your markdown with a link on stackedit?